# php date library for reiteration

Tags: php, date, recurrence

I need something for a PHP project that will enable me to get back odd date like "every other Saturday in the Month" or "every fourth Friday of the month". Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I hope this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380410/repeating-events-on-the-nth-weekday-of-every-month

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('y')));

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'fourth friday'));

?>
```

This will give you the date of fourth friday of current month

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but for reference:

https://github.com/tplaner/When

Comment: Carlos, link-only answers are discouraged because the link may not work in the future.  Can you expand your answer by including or discussing the relevant information from the link you posted?